# YouTube video streaming for Cardboard android app (Not using Unity)

Tags: android, youtube, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to put YouTube streaming video inside my app for Cardboard (Android). I want the video to be streamed side by side like in Cardboard View But i have found source for playing from resources or the sd card! if anybody having idea for this use case,would be appreciated. Thanks.